# Stability of linux

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, kde, stability

I have one "theoretical" question regarding the stability of Linux. 
Is there a way that somebody verifies it?

I recently installed Debian 9 (KDE) and given my experience with other distros, I was expecting to see every time that I shut it off the logo or somehting similar (like it happens in Mint/Ubuntu) but there's nothing like this. Same when I open the laptop.

I am worried if the installation is stable.

Comment: Why would a logo appearing on boot/reboot determine a distributions stability?

Comment: well if all the distros do it and only one doesn't is suspicious. Naively at least

Comment: Most *popular* distros use it. Usually the ones that try to be the most user friendly. The logo is simply an unnecessary feature they add to appeal to the desktop OS market, and has nothing to do with stability. You can configure any Linux distribution to display whatever logo you want on boot/reboot, given you know/have the right software to do it.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that. I thought it was something standard. On the other hand, do you have any suggestions about checking the stability?

Answer (score 1):

Better dig through your logs looking for some key words like "error", "warning" or "panic". They're in `/var/log` and the right tool is `grep`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are some errors. One further question is if it is acceptable to have some errors or it shouldn't have any at all?

Comment: @hal: that depends entirely on what the errors are. Look them up.